# Do something if WebView url contains a string

Tags: android, webview, android-studio, webviewclient, webchromeclient

I have a `WebView` in which I load a webpage. In this webpage the user needs to do some actions. A specific action needs to be executed when the user arrives on a specific webpage. This action should execute automatically.

How can I continuously check the current URL in the WebView and connect an action to a certain condition?

An example code is:

```
String url = wv.getUrl();
if (url.contains("string"))
{
    code = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("value=") + 6);
    dialog.dismiss(); //action
}
```

However, where can I place this so it continuously checks the URL of the `WebView`? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have,

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
  {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {               

        String url = webView.getUrl();
        if (url.contains("string"))
        {
           code = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("value=") + 6);
           dialog.dismiss(); //action
        }
        return false;                            
    }
 }
```

Ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you so much! However, this does not return me the url which I want to load but returns the current url, so prior to loading the destination url - which I want to retrieve...

Comment: Oh but your question was you wanted to know the current URL.. Take a look at onPageFinished too. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,java.lang.String)

Comment: My bad! Sorry. I got it fixed now, completely missed onPageFinished. Thanks, I'll mark your answer as correct.